# How to check if second argument in test case is absent in python?

Tags: python

I have the following Python code:

```
test.assert_equals(string_chunk('everlong'), ['everlong']);

def string_chunk(string, n):
    s=[]    
    i=0
    if n<=0 or n==[]or n==None:
        return []
    elif n>len(string):
       return [string]
    else:   
        for i in range(0,len(string),i+n):
             s.append(string[i:i+n])
        return s
```

The code is supposed to return string chunks of certain size `n`, and is also supposed to check if `n` is empty or not passed as a parameter. It is giving an error `string_chunk()` takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given). How do I provide a default argument so that I can call this with one or two arguments?

Comment: What is your question? What is this code supposed to do? Does it work?

Comment: There are two ways to handle "optional" arguments, either by using [*default parameter values*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values), or by using [*arbitrary argument lists*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: Added a bit more explanation and clarified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with test cases, testing or the assertion you are trying.

Your code simply fails because your function `string_chunk` expects *exactly* two arguments, but you are giving it exactly one.

If you want `n` to be an optional parameter, use a default value:

```
def string_chunk(string, n=None):
    if not n or n < 0:
        return []
    # rest of the logic here
```

`not n` will account for all cases of falsy values for `n`, among them `None`, 0 or the empty list `[]`.

edit:

From your comment I'm assuming you actually want

```
return [string]
```

instead of

```
return []
```

I can only guess, though, your specifications are unclear.

Comment: thank you,the previous error got resolved but it is not working when the value of n is absent i.e when the string only is given

Comment: thank you it is solved i had to also check for n being only integer value and not any other which i forgot.Your answer was really helpful.